# Regular expression to parse through novel text

Tags: regex, file-io

I'm trying to read from a file that contains the text of a novel. I'd like to read each successive word, but of course the fact that there is punctuation in the novel makes that difficult.

I need to read just words in the novel, so ignore characters like "," "!" and "?", but I need to include certain non-alphabet characters such as the apostrophe that are actually part of words.

I'm not great with regular expressions, but my feeling is that this regex only grabs characters, but doesn't account for apostrophes:

```
[^A-Za-z]+
```

Can anyone help me get a regex that will delimit by words, ignoring punctuation, yet keeping apostrophes and other characters that form parts of words?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just include the other special characters you want to include inside the `[]` brackets.  Some characters might need to be escaped.  I've included the apostrophe for you below:

```
/([^A-Za-z']+)/
```

Comment: This is not the answer.  It translates to "Capture anything that is NOT a letter or an apostrophe.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern should look something like this:

`\b[a-zA-Z]+[\']*[a-zA-Z]*\b`

It accounts for word boundaries and allows 1 apostrophe.  Other special characters can be put into the 2nd set of square brackets.